# React Native iOS App, crash on Release Mode

Tags: iphone, xcode8, react-native-ios

Hi I am facing an issue when I am releasing my app, I am using the *react-native 0.39* , but I have a problem, the app works perfect when I run it as debug mode using *react-native run-ios* and when I run it from xCode,  but when I run as release mode using *react-native run-ios --configuration Release* the app crash imediatly after show it, but here the problem when I run the app in release mode in xCode the app works again perfect, even all my *testflight* user have the same issue, i have followed the correct steps in order to deploy:

1. Generate the local bundle

   `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/myapp/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'`
2. Change the url in AppDelegate

   `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`
3. Copy the bundle and the assets to my project

[image: this is the structure in my project]

Any idea why I am getting this issue ?
the information about my environment is the bellow

- xCode 8.2.1
- MacOS Sierra
- BaseiOS 8(I have tried change to each version available in my xCode 8,9,10)

Regards

Comment: How where u able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions maybe they can help you:

1. Clean the build through Xcode
2. Click on the project in Xcode and you can see two targets. Normally YOUR_APP and YOUR_APPTests. Check YOUR_APPTests Build phases -> LinkBinary with Libraries. You will need to add libReact.a and libART.a
3. Try to run 'release' mode in xcode directly and test with simulator see if it crashes. You can setup this in 'Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme -> Run'.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer, but i am still having the same scenario,